# How to write a string in a specific position of file in C

Tags: c, file-io, line

I have some strings that are like `LineNumber.Number` which come from a previous code. I split them to 2 variable `LineNumber` and `LineContent` and after that I want to write the `LineContent` in the appropriate line in the file. But the `LineNumber`s are not ordered, so maybe I first should write in line number 300 then in Line number 5 and so on. How can I do this with  C language ? The file is initially empty so I cannot count `\n` s.

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide _from-scratch_ coding service. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.:-)

Comment: If the file is empty it's not clear what it even means to write to line 300.  At any rate: there's no standard mechanism to keep track of where in a text file each line begins; programs which need to know this must create and maintain their own index.  There's also the issue that if the file is not empty, if line 300 already exists, and if the new text you're writing to line 300 is not the same length as the old line 300, the operating system is not going to shift the remainder of the file around, so your code would have to deal with that issue as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First open that file in r+ mode , `p = fopen("filename.txt","r+");`
2. Take any `char acline[80]` array.
3. Then use `fgets(acline,80,p)` this will copy data stored in line 1 in file `acline[80]`
4. Then search for specific position using this approach

   ```
   for(int i=0;acline[i]!=0;i++)
   {
     if(bla bla bla)
     { //your code }
     else {}
   }
   ```
5. `char buffer[] = { 'x' , 'y' , 'z' };`
6. Note position of i then use `fseek(p,0,SEEK_SET);` in place of 0 put position of i and then write or use `fwrite (buffer , sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), p);`

Answer (score 1):

You could allocate an array of C string pointers according to max line number encountered.  When max increases as you go, you reallocate.

Each time your code sees new content for a line, it reallocates the C string, and copies the new content.

When done, you iterate your array, writing line by line to the file.

Answer (score 1):

If I have correctly understood you problem, you have an unordered *list* of *string items* of the form `LineNumber.LineContent` and you want that after processing it, you get a file where all `LineContent` are written in correct position.

I cannot imagine a better way than :

- put all your items in an array (provided it can fit in memory)
- sort the array (look at the `qsort` function)
- print the array on item at a time, adding blank lines if there are holes in the numbers